# Material-UI Next js Link Button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, href, next.js

I am working on a Server-Side-Rendering React Project, built with Next-JS and Material-UI.
and i want to apply To Material Ui [button](https://material-ui.com/api/button/) -> the [Link with Dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes)

how can i do this? i would [apply React Router Link](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#button),but it is different...

my problem is that it has another properties required such as "as" property.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

what worked for me (inspired from [this comment in Github](https://gist.github.com/herr-vogel/0b5d4f3c28f08dc6cc4a2fd4f7b4a4df#gistcomment-3070513)):

```
 <Link
     href={'/static/[dynamic]'}
     as={'/static/' + someJsString}
     passHref>
     <Button
        component="a">
        // other component ...
     </Button>
  </Link>
```

for version `v10+`:

```
<Link
    href={`/static/${someJsString}`}
    passHref>
    <Button
       component="a">
       // other component ...
    </Button>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**

Starting `next.js` v10+ you don't need to specify `as` with [Automatic `href` Resolution](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10#automatic-resolving-of-href) so the above code can be written as:

```
<Link
     href={'/static/' + someJsString}
     passHref>
     <Button
        component="a">
        // other component ...
     </Button>
  </Link>
```

Comment: is this a button? material ui styled button?

Comment: @adirabargil This is a [Link](https://material-ui.com/components/links/) but you can do the same for a button. Just remove `passHref` coz it will only give a meaning if used with `<a/>` tag (what `Link` is used for). Can you be more specific about what you want to do? e.g. want to use `<a/>` tag in a `mui-styled` button component or just want to wrap a `Button` with `next/link`? I have done both.  See the [diff](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag).

Comment: @adirabargil I think the accepted answer has already covered your case. Anyways I would like to add that you no more required to add `as` prop starting `next.js` v10+