# Material UI Pagination + Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I am implementing Material UI paging in a developed application using NEXT JS.

I started by adding the pagination component :

```
        <Pagination
          siblingCount={2}
          page={parseInt(props.page||1)}
          count={parseInt(props.total_pages)}
          renderItem={(item) => (
            <>
            <PaginationItem
              component={MaterialUiLink}
              query={query}
              item={item}
              {...item}
            />
            </>
          )}
        />
      </>
```

Then I defined a functional component that will be props of PaginationItem (component={MaterialUiLink}) :

```
export function MaterialUiLink({item, query, ...props}:MaterialUiLinkProps) {
  return <Link href={{
    pathname: searchListing,
    query: {...query, page: item.page}
  }}><Button {...props}></Button></Link>;
}
```

But when I went to the page and opened the devtools console, I found two errors:

- Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `ForwardRef(ButtonBase)`. Expected an element type that can hold a ref. Did you accidentally provide a plain function component instead? For more information see https://mui.com/r/caveat-with-refs-guide
- Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
  Check the render method of `MuiButtonBaseRoot`.

At no point did I define a MuiButtonBase component, where does the error come from? How can I handle this ?

Comment: this answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/61364541/18457414

Comment: It didn't help. I tried it